# How to solve the error of “Gave up waiting for root device”

Tags: boot

I'm using ubuntu 15.04.

Yesterday I was using my ubuntu and the computer power supply cut off.

Now today I started my computer I got this message

Gave up waiting for root device. Common problems:

- Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)

  - Check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?)
  - Check root= (did the system wait for the right device)
- Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; ls /dev)
  ALERT! /dev/disk/by-uuid/96889309-5f73-4688-8354-e64cd1bb158f does not exist. Dropping to a shell!

BusyBox v1.21.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.21.0-1ubuntu1) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of build-in commands.

(initramfs)

I typed exit command but nothing happened.

I used testdisk command from the live Ubuntu CD but the testdisk is not detecting the hard drive

I installed boot repair tool but it is not showing me Recommended repair button.
[Boot Repair](https://i.stack.imgur.com/03VNt.png)

Then I clicked on bootinfo summary and I got this

http://paste.ubuntu.com/13818351/

What is wrong with my computer

How do I recover the data

Please Help me Guys...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a solution with a Live-CD:

- sudo mount /dev/sdXY /mnt

Repair Grub2:

- sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sdX 
  (not sdXY)

Reboot.

After starting system:

- sudo update-grub